# Win32 edit control doesn't have caret

Tags: c++, winapi, textbox, edit, caret

I'm creating a hybrid win32/D2D form, and I'm trying to create an edit control. I must be missing something silly, because my caret isn't appearing, nor does it respond to ShowCaret(). The code that creates the box and the code from the WndProc is below:

The creation:

```
HWND usernamebox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,L"EDIT",L"", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 90,105,250,25,hwnd,(HMENU)1,hinst,NULL);
/*Create a Segoe UI font f, etc.*/
SendMessageW(usernamebox,WM_SETFONT,WPARAM(f),NULL);
```

The WndProc:

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT: {
    SetTextColor((HDC)wpa,RGB(84,84,84));       
    return (LRESULT)editbrush; //a white hbrush
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The edit control should show the caret when it gets the focus. So call SetFocus to transfer the focus to the edit control.

Answer (score 0):

I ended being able to solve it by letting my case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT fall through and return the default window proc. I guess I was missing something I needed to do in that event.